# Python String Manipulation - Replace Function to create Caesar Cipher

Tags: python

I'm running into a problem with my code, I suspect it's my use of the replace method but I'm unsure. I want to write a code that will encrypt the string referenced by the variable plaintext using the caesar cipher with a shift of 1 then store the result in variable ciphertext; storing it is where my value is incorrect.

```
plaintext = 'thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog'
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
ciphertext = 'thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog'

for i in range(len(plaintext)):
    j = plaintext[i]
    j_index = alphabet.index(j)
    if j_index + 13 >= 26:
        j_index = (j_index + 13) % 26
    else:
        j_index+=13
    ciphertext = ciphertext.replace(j,alphabet[j_index])
    print(ciphertext[i])
    
print(ciphertext)
```

When I print each individual character it gives me the results I want, but when I print ciphertext as a whole, some of the letters are different and the value is incorrect. Appreciate help, TIA.

I want my output to be: 'gurdhvpxoebjasbkwhzcfbiregurynmlqbt', instead I am getting 'turquickbrbwnfbkwumcfbirrturlnmlqbt'

Edited to fix code and add output.

Comment: please enter the expected output

Comment: `j = plaintext[i]` you're referrencing `plaintext` even though you have never defined it, I am assuming this is a typo?

Comment: Imagine your plain text is "a".  You first have i = 0 and change the "a" to an "n".  Then we i = 13, you'll change the "n" back to an "a".  Your mistake is that you don't distinguish between characters that have already been encoded and those that haven't yet been encoded.  You'll get the wrong answer for every letter between a and m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the characters are getting replace more than once because we are replacing in whole string not at the exact location

```
plaintext = 'thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog'
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
ciphertext = 'thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog'
ciphertextfinal = ''
for i in range(len(plaintext)):
    j = plaintext[i]
    j_index = alphabet.index(j)
    if j_index + 13 >= 26:
        j_index = (j_index + 13) % 26
    else:
        j_index+=13
    ciphertext = ciphertext.replace(j,alphabet[j_index])
    ciphertextfinal += ciphertext[i]
    print(ciphertext[i])
    
print(ciphertextfinal)
#prints gurdhvpxoebjasbkwhzcfbiregurynmlqbt
```

I just used the replaced position and made a string out of it by concating into a variable

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly now. For added clarification, I thought my code was looking at the individual location of each letter in the plaintext and the for loop was iterating through those individual characters. Do you mind further explaining why it was replacing them more than once?

Comment: your string  -   abcdef,   after loop 1 new string:  cbcdef ( a to c),  after loop 2 : cdcdef  (b to d), after loop 3: ededef ( c to e), after loop 4: efefef ( d to f) and so on

Comment: so you see if you change in the same string, it would also replace the old values which are fine but its wrong.